# How to connect Iphone with xamarin studio?

Tags: iphone, xamarin

I need to connect Iphone with xamarin studio,I connect my phone but it will not display in debugging devices.

Comment: Have you added it to the list of development devices in Xcode already?

Comment: I am c# developer so I do know Xcode and all I just know xamarin studio?

Comment: Are you on Windows or Mac?

Answer (score 2):

Before you can deploy your application to a device, you need to have an active subscription with the Apple Developer Program. Visit the Apple Developer Portal to get registered.

Apple has outlined a set of special guidelines that developers must follow in order to do everything from deploying to a device to shipping to the App Store. These steps ensure that everything you create or use during the development process, including your applications and devices, can be traced back to your Apple Developer account.

...Continued at http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/device_provisioning/

Comment: Apple is (other than Google and Microsoft) only company that makes you pay to even deploy (and test) to/on device.

Answer (score 0):

Just because you're a Xamarin developer, doesn't mean you're not going to need to occasionally do things in Xcode.

This post should point you in the right direction:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/135382/developer-option-is-not-available-under-settings-menu-why

Sounds like the option has been moved to somewhere other than the XCode Organizer in versions newer than XCode 6. It's apparently now under Window -> Devices in XCode.